# Permissions: What's the right way to give Apache more user permissions?

Tags: permissions, php, apache-httpd

Context: I am making an in-browser control panel that gives me one button access to a library of scripts (.sh and .php) that I've written to process various kinds of data for a project. It's a "one stop shop" for managing data for this project.

I've made good progress. I have apache, PHP and MySQL running, and I have my front end up at http://localhost. Good so far!

Now the problem I'm having: I have an index.php which works fine, except the default apache user (which on my machine is called "_www") seemingly doesn't have permissions to run some of my scripts.

So when I do:

```
<?php
    echo `ls`;
    echo `whoami`;
    echo `/Path/To/Custom/Script.sh`;
?>
```

I get the output of `ls` and `whoami`, but I get nothing back from the custom script. If I run the custom script as me (in an interactive shell), of course it works.

Finally, my question: What's the *right* way to configure this. Have the webserver run as me? Or change permissions so that _www can run my custom scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first-best thing would be to put the script in a standard location (such as `/usr/local/bin`) where the web server would have sufficient permissions to execute it.

If that's not an option, you can change the group of the script using `chgrp groupname path`, then make it executable for the group by `chmod g+x path`. If the `_www` user isn't already in that group, add it to the group by `usermod -aG groupname _www`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, it's better to give the _www group permission to execute your scripts.

Use an ACL to extend the permissions on your *.sh scripts to allow a user in the _www group execute privilege:

```
cd /Path/To/Custom
setfacl -m g:_www:rx *.sh
```

Also check each directory component of /Path/To/Custom & verify that apache has permission to access (i.e. 'see') the scripts in /Path/To/Custom:

```
ls -ld /Path
ls -ld /Path/To
ls -ld /Path/To/Custom
```

Each directory component above should grant apache a minimum of execute permission apart from the final component (*Custom*) where apache needs both execute & read permission. e.g. if all the directory components above have *other* permissions of *r-x* then apache has all the access rights it needs to find your scripts in the *Custom* directory.