# Group Permission on public_html

Tags: permissions, group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permissions: What's the right way to give Apache more user permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9241/permissions-whats-the-right-way-to-give-apache-more-user-permissions)

Before I knew better, I used /home/someuser/public_html/scripts as a place from which shared scripts could be accessed by various users' php scripts.

```
include('/home/someuser/public_html/scripts/somefile.php');
```

Something changed when we went from one server to another and now the only way that was working was to set public_html to 0755. Since we now have some customers with access to their own accounts, this is not acceptable. I tested a work around by adding a user to the same group as someuser and putting another folder at /home/someuser/test_folder and setting it to 0750. Now my users who share the group can access test_folder. A user that is not in the group cannot, but if I chmod public_html from 755 to 750, I get permission errors even from the users that are in the same group. I checked lsattr and the only attrib that is set is "I" on public_html

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: Your description isn't very clear, but if I understand correctly you did the right thing. Copy-paste the output of `ls -ld /home/someuser /home/someuser/public_html /home/someuser/public_html/scripts /home/someuser/public_html/scripts/somefile.php` and of `su -c groups user1` where user1 is not in the group.

Comment: I found out that I was mistaken. public_html was (is) in the "nobody" group, and so is apache, so my grouping idea won't work.

Comment: Don't let any file belong to `nobody` or run any process as `nobody`: that's what it's for. Create another group. And use access control lists (ACLs) to manage permissions, that's almost always the answer to website permission woes.

Comment: Or [How to configure permissions to allow apache to securely have access to a file in a shared environment?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44919)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was `# setfacl -m g:someuser:rx /home/someuser/public_html`

Read that like this 
"Set File Access Control List, Modify, Group:someuser:read,execute, /home/someuser/public_html"

This [forum question](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/implications-of-making-users-members-of-apache-group-730046/) is what pointed me in the right direction.